# Linux memory allocation for user's process (buddy allocator)

Tags: memory, virtual-memory

I'm studying memory allocation in Linux and I have a question about the buddy allocator. Reading the documentation available on [kernel.org](https://kernel.org) I've learn that the buddy allocator is responsible for the allocation of physical pages (through the __alloc_pages() function).

I'm wondering if the buddy system (and the __alloc_pages() function) is involved in the allocation of pages to user's processes, or if it allocates pages only for kernel's processes.

Summing up, my question is: if a user's process needs to be loaded into the physical memory, the buddy allocator is involved?

Answer (score 1):

IMO, there is no difference between a user process's page and a kernel process's page. Hence, I believe that whenever anything needed to be allocated on the physical memory, the buddy allocator will be involved.